# How to use AutoModelForSequenceClassification for Multiclass Classification

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, loss-function, multiclass-classification

I am trying to create a multiclass classification model using **AutoModelForSequenceClassification**. Currently, I have a dataset that looks like this:

[image: sample data]

Where the *encoded_label* column is the result of the LabelEncoder from sklearn.preprocessing where I have 7 unique labels in total..

I have already created the necessary data dictionaries of this using the *DatasetDict* function from *datasets* and preprocessed the data using the following code:

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
import numpy as np
import torch

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME)

def preprocess_data(examples):
    # take a batch of texts
    text = examples['text']
    # encode them
    encoding = tokenizer(text, padding="max_length", truncation=True, max_length=512)
    
    # add labels
    encoding['labels'] = torch.Tensor(examples['labels'])

    return encoding

encoded_dataset = data.map(preprocess_data,
                           batched=True, 
                           remove_columns = data['train'].column_names)
```

I have also loaded the model using

```
MODEL_NAME = 'google/bert_uncased_L-12_H-768_A-12'
model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL_NAME,                                                            problem_type="multi_class_classification", 
                                                           num_labels=len(labels),
                                                           id2label=id2label,
                                                           label2id=label2id)
model.to(device)
```

and am currently training with the following code:

```
NUM_EPOCHS = 30         # number of epochs to run
save_every = 1
LEARNING_RATE = 1e-4       # initial learning rate of model

optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=LEARNING_RATE)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

num_training_steps = NUM_EPOCHS * len(train_dataloader)
num_val_steps = NUM_EPOCHS * len(valid_dataloader)

lr_scheduler = get_scheduler(
    name="linear",
    optimizer=optimizer,
    num_warmup_steps=WARMUP_STEPS,
    num_training_steps=num_training_steps
)

random_state = np.random.RandomState(seed = 2022)
torch.manual_seed(3407)

training_loss = list()
validation_loss = list()

for epoch in tqdm(range(1, NUM_EPOCHS+1), total = NUM_EPOCHS, position = 0, leave = True):
    
    optimizer.step()
    lr_scheduler.step()
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    
    if epoch > -1:
        epoch_loss = 0
        epoch_val_loss = 0
        
        model.train()
        
        for batch in tqdm(train_dataloader, total = len(train_dataloader),position = 0, leave = True):
            batch = {k: v.to(device) for k, v in batch.items()}
            outputs = model(**batch)
            
            loss = criterion(outputs.logits, batch['labels'])
            # print("Loss computed {}".format(loss))
            
            loss.backward()
            
            epoch_loss += loss.item()
            optimizer.step()

            lr_scheduler.step()
            optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        model.eval()
        with torch.no_grad():
            # print("Eval mode")
            for batch in tqdm(valid_dataloader, total = len(valid_dataloader), position = 0, leave = True):
                batch = {k : v.to(device) for k, v in batch.items()}
                outputs = model(**batch)
                
                val_loss = criterion(outputs.logits, batch['labels'])
                # print("Loss computed eval {}".format(loss))
                epoch_val_loss += val_loss.item()
        
        training_loss.append(epoch_loss/num_training_steps)
        validation_loss.append(epoch_val_loss/num_val_steps)
        
        pd.DataFrame({'train':training_loss,'valid':validation_loss}).to_csv("SMALL_BERT"+'_loss.csv')
        print(f'Epoch {epoch+0:03}: | Training Loss: {training_loss[-1]:.5f} | Validation Loss: {validation_loss[-1]:.5f}')
```

Currently, the model is somehow not learning anything, it is predicting the same class for all the samples in the test set.. I am now wondering if I am wrong with anything (e.g. did I encode the labels wrong? Should it be one-hot encoded such as
**NEWS -> [1,0,0,0], ENTERTAINMENT -> [0,0,1,0], ETC..**), Do I have a mistake in using the Loss function? or is it simply because my Learning Rate is too high or too low? Because when I train it on a small dataset (e.g. 10000 train samples, 3000 validation, 6000 test), it does not behave like this..

Comment: Hi! I am working on a similar problem and I found this: https://www.alexanderjunge.net/blog/til-multi-label-automodelforsequenceclassification/ -- this might answer some of your questions here. Seems like you do have to one-hot encode it each time!